# Using a sound sensor to collect data every 6 seconds and display if no sound is detected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors

I'm trying to collect sound data from a sound sensor connected to a raspberry pi 4. Right now I have it set up where it will print 1 every time sound is detected. However, when I try to add an else statement to print 0 when no sound is detected, it will only print 0 even if there is constant sound being played.

This is the code that works fine displaying 1 every time sound is detected.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

SND_SNSR = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(SND_SNSR,GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(SND_SNSR) == GPIO.LOW):
        print("1")
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

And this is the code I have for trying to get it to display every 6 seconds and display either 1 or 0 for sound or no sound but it's not working.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

SND_SNSR = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(SND_SNSR,GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(SND_SNSR) == GPIO.LOW):
        print("1")
    else:
        print("0")
    time.sleep(6)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried printing out what the actual value of `GPIO.input(SND_SNSR)` is, rather than just 1 or 0, in order to try to debug what's going on? That would probably be really useful for us all to know.

Comment: I don't quite understand your statement of your problem.  You say that when you only print "1", everything works fine.  But if you add an `else` clause to print "0" under other conditions, you don't get the right behavior.  I'm not sure that this description makes any sense.  Your code performs one iteration of the check and print ever 6 seconds.  If it works when you just print 1, it has to work just as well when you print either 1 or 0.  The logic is so simple.  It can't be any other way.  For example, adding the `else` could not have caused 1s to not be printed when they used to be.

Comment: Maybe you are suffering from buffering Try adding `-u` flag, i.e. `python3 -u YourScript.py`

Comment: @RandomDavis When I print the value of `GPIO.input(SND_SNSR)` it prints 1. However, If I remove `print("1")` and only have `GPIO.input(SND_SNSR)` it will print 0. I'm not to sure why that is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried it with the `-u` flag and it didn't seem to work, it still just prints 0 every 6 seconds even if the sensor is receiving constant sound.

Comment: Try replacing the `GPIO.LOW` with `GPIO.HIGH` as the pin is set to high.